# Does amla (Indian gooseberry) contain lots of vitamin C?

Tags: vitamin-c

The rumor is that an Indian gooseberry contains vitamin C so much as a sum of two/three oranges. Is that true?

Comment: I think that this question would fit better on Biology SE, because it's not really a health question (make up a fruit).

Comment: Note though some fruits might contain more Vitamin C, the digestion of nutrients by the body is a complicated process and you might not want to choose fruits solely based on this factor. Much of the noise behind VC etc. might just well be marketing push by the fruit sellers.